# css picture alignment for my website

Tags: css, image, alignment, photo

Hello every one I am trying to align my photo links to my image converters, please take a look at my website https://www.tagadoor.com/converter/ you will see that oil painting is on top of emboss two link, this is my css

```
 <style>
.header {width: 98.6%;}
.pdf{border-radius : 11px;}
.pdf{height : 37px; width : 183px;}
.pdf{vertical-align : top; margin : 18px;}
.pdf{font-style: oblique; font-size: 80%; font-weight: bold;}
.pdf{cursor: pointer;}
.piper{
width: 170px;
}
div.pipy {
display: inline-block;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
   colum: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 43px;
  -moz-column-gap: 43px;
   column-gap: 43px;
}
div.pipy{
margin-top: 33px;

}

span {font-style: italic;}
 </style>
```

Also please tell me any suggestion you might have, all of the converters work if you want to test it out. Thank you so much for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 introduced 'figures', and 'figcaptions' along with it. By wrapping an image and 'figcaption' within a 'figure' tag, you can keep them together. I like this method because it's clean and doesn't require any CSS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure

Comment: Thank you did you look at my web site just to confirm?

Comment: I did. Here's how I implemented it, though it looks like you may want the <A> tag to only apply to the image?   <a title="Background" href="http://www.tagadoor.com/background/">
    <figure>
      <img id="hover" class="card" src="https://www.tagadoor.com/pictures/uploads/taga3.png" alt="">
   <figcaption>Background</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>

Comment: Thank you more issues for me but it will work, thank you!!!! Did you happen to convert a couple of photo's?

Comment: I didn't before - but I just gave it a shot. That's pretty cool, man! I did a PDF and it did the second page; I guess it wouldn't know which page I wanted? The PNG -> JPEG worked really well.

Comment: took alot of coding to get is that way but it works I am just trying to get to css to work out...

Comment: I actually taught my self how to code php css javascript  jquery

Comment: Congrats! I like what you're doing. Stay with it, and remember ABC.. Always Be Coding. :)